# Вывести главное изображение страницы через background в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Для вывода изображения на странице использую код в шаблоне конкретной страницы:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Таким образом, изображение страницы выводится через `img`.

По существующему дизайну, изображение предпочтительнее выводить через `background`. Так:

```
 <div class="header-image" style="background-image: url('img/slider/slide_6.jpg');"></div>
```

Это возможно? Как это можно сделать?

**UPD**

Нашла решение [тут](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115954/featured-image-as-background-image-on-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`the_post_thumbnail_url`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/the_post_thumbnail_url):

> Выводит на экран URL миниатюры установленной для текущей записи. Если миниатюры нет вернет `NULL` (ничего не выведет).

```
<div class="header-image" style="background-image: url('<?php
  the_post_thumbnail_url( 'full' );
?>');"></div>
```

Если нужно получить изображение за пределами [вордпрессовского цикла](https://wp-kama.ru/id_119/chto-takoe-tsikl-the-loop-v-wordpress.html), то попробуйте [`get_the_post_thumbnail_url`](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_post_thumbnail_url):

> Получает URL установленной для записи миниатюры. Если миниатюры нет, то вернет `false`.

```
<div class="header-image" style="background-image: url('<?php 
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );
?>');"></div>
```

Comment: вроде должно было сработать, но выводит пустой url. может надо что-то добавить в media.php ? даже при выводе `img` -  `full` не срабатывает. картинка всегда с фиксированными размерами...

Comment: нашла решение тут https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115954/featured-image-as-background-image-on-pages

Comment: Если вызываете вне вордпрессовского цикла, то попробуйте `echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );`. https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_post_thumbnail_url

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение работает